# How to change operator from 0 to 9 on Nortel Norstar phone system

Tags: phone-call

When people call in they ignore the prompts and dial 0. We'd like to change the operator from 0 to 9. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the quality of your prompts.  If your prompts are not helping me get the information I want, I will try for the Operator.  Changing the operator key will just get you a bunch of unsatisfied customers.  Many will hangup and go elsewhere if they can.  Is this what you want?

Track why your customers are pressing 0, and rearrange your prompts to get the most important prompts early in the list.  Add new prompts if needed.  When changing your prompts you may want to indicate that they have changed early in the prompt messages.

Comment: We have changed our prompts but we are still looking to keep people from listening and just clicking 0.

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to setup a voice mail jail?